# Concatenate url() in Twig

Tags: theming, 8

I tried to do something that I thought was fairly simple, but it's giving an error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in __TwigTemplate_dd3a187031be000574aa6b2149e8b2daacd4f1d086638752b5928811c46b8adf->doDisplay() (line 132 of vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(462) : eval()'d code).

What caused it:

```
{% set support_url = url('<front>') ~ 'support' %}
```

So I tried something:

```
{{ url('<front>') }}<br />
{% set support_url = url('<front>') %}
{{ support_url }}<br />
{% set support_url = url('<front>') ~ 'support' %}
{{ support_url }}<br />
```

The result of the above is:

> http://www.example.com/
>
> http://www.example.com/
>
> Arraysupport

What is going on?

Comment: `url()` returns a render array, which Twig knows how to render. At the moment you're concatenating a string and an array, hence the output

Comment: I see. So I suppose there is no way to do what I was trying. I would have to pass the front page URL as a variable in preprocess.

Comment: Ah, you helped me find how. It's easy: `{% set support_url = url('<front>')|render ~ 'support' %}`

Comment: That doesn't really make sense however. If you want to builda different url, you should provide a different route to url() ? If you go there, why bother with url() at all, you could just as well just hardcode the URL in the first place?

Comment: The URL doesn't have a route, and I'm printing the link inside some translated text.

Comment: You can make use of _link_ or _file_url_ functions. They both accept URI.

Answer (score 3):

The url function returns a render array, so you can't concatenate it with a string.  You must first convert it to a string.

try [render_var()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3ArenderVar/8.2.x):

```
{% set support_url = render_var(url('<front>')) ~ 'support' %}

<h1>{{ support_url }}</h1>
```

This will convert the render array created by the url function to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if my contribution is useful, but I had a problem with a **multilanguage** site and I solved it in this way.

The drawback was, that the language is not shown /ES, / EN, /pt-br, etc. It always showed the url of the base language, that is, EN.

```
{% set support_url = path('<front>') ~ '/node/102' %}

{% set base_url = render_var(url('<front>')) ~ support_url %} 

<a href="{{ base_url }}">
    <h2 class="block-title">{{ 'Change'|t}}    </h2>
</a>
```